# Kali Linux stuck on boot with a fast flashing cursor

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux

When I Started my kali Linux, it got stuck with a fast flashing cursor. I disabled quiet boot mode and here's what I got,

(The cursor blinks pretty fast  for a few seconds and then with normal speed)
[image]
On previous boot , I remember installing Vega!!!

It's Kali rolling 2017.1 dist-upgraded from 2016.1

Also I cant get into any terminal mode through Alt-F* for a few minutes(the screen switches back and forth between consoles). I can boot into recovery mode!

It's a Lenovo Z570 laptop dual booted with kali and windows 10. I installed bumblebee for my optimus card and so far worked fine!

Thanks in Advance!!

**P.S:** I Deleted and reinstalled Kali. so I'm not looking for answers anymore. but I'm leaving this question open in hopes of being helpful to someone if answered.

Comment: its might be due to incomplete update, once login screen reached press ctrl+alt+f4 and goto terminal mode,perform update and upgrade it would be resolved

Comment: I Tried. it's still in the same condition. But the update goes perfectly!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have repution yet to make a comment.

It seems that linux is waiting for a response from the wlan, and gets stuck there.

Try to load the CLI mode with control + alt + f2

Once there go to this directory and modify the file "interfaces" with:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Probably the problem is here so, remove every line and keep it like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Try to boot again.

Comment: It's not working dude!!!